# Textbox on focus leads us to a Combobox

Tags: jquery, html, combobox, textbox

I have a situation here, i am having a combo box with values. If that field is focussed then it becomes a combo box with values that user can select. When the user selects any value then it acts like a textbox and not like a combo box(i.e., the arrow of it hides of and look & feel wise a plain text box with the value selected - as i thought)

I dont know why is the confusion?

let me re-phrase:

I have a tabular data, in which i have lots of editable data on which majorly are combo boxes; so it is not looking nicer with the arrows coming up several places in the tabular data.

Now, i have seen somewhere this feature but not remembering it:

1. I need to show textfields **types** or span when data is being displayed
2. But when i do a click or dblclick; it shows me the combobox at that point of click.

### Thanks in advance

GOK

Comment: Perhaps you can rephrase this - a bit of code -what you expected, what you actually got?

Comment: What is your actual question then? Do you want TextBox or do you want ComboBox? Can you rephrase your question.

Comment: have different elements, handle the click event so that the text box is hidden and the combo is shown. handle the select event on combo so show the text box back. and hide/show your elements accordingly.

Comment: I don't really see a question here =/.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the autocomplete plugin of Jquery as [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default)

```
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",
  "Erlang",
  "Fortran",
  "Groovy",
  "Haskell",
  "Java",
  "JavaScript",
  "Lisp",
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
  "Python",
  "Ruby",
  "Scala",
  "Scheme"
];
$(<INPUTSELECTOR>).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
```